# SQL script for retrieving 5 unique values in a table ( google big query )

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am looking for a query where I can get unique values(5) in a table. For example.
The table consists of more 100+ columns. Is there any way I can get unique values.

I am using google big query and tried this option

```
select col1 col2 ... coln
from tablename
where col1 is not null and col2 is not null
group by col1,col2... coln
order by col1, col2... coln
limit 5
```

But problem is it gives zero records if all the column are null

Thanks
R

Comment: If it removes all the records when the columns are NULL *and* you want NULL values, then simply remove the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: If your `GROUP BY` list is the same as your `SELECT` list, you can use `SELECT DISTINCT` to get unique values.

Comment: distinct is not supported in Google  big query. I don't want null values, I need 5 unique values for each column

Comment: You tagged this `mysql`.

Comment: Could you post some sample data and the results you're trying to get from it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be able to do this in Google bigquery, assuming that the types for the columns are compatible:

```
select colname, colval
from (select 'col1' as colname, col1 as colvalue
      from t
      where col1 is not null
      group by col1
      limit 5
     ),
     (select 'col2' as colname, col2 as colvalue
      from t
      where col2 is not null
      group by col2
      limit 5
     ),
     . . .
```

For those not familiar with the syntax, a comas in the `from` clause means `union all`, not `cross join` in this dialect.  Why did they have to change this?

Answer (score 0):

Try This one, i hope it works

```
   ;With CTE as (
    select * ,ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by isnull(col1,''),isnull(col2,'')... isnull(coln,'') order by isnull(col1,'')) row_id
    from tablename
    ) select * from CTE where row_id =1
```